# In lambda calculus, can the parameter of abstraction be a non-variable lambda expression?

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

In short, my main confusion is between the two concept `variable` and `lambda expression`:

I am  reading this reference [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~horwitz/CS704-NOTES/1.LAMBDA-CALCULUS.html#syntax):

> The syntax of (pure) lambda expressions is defined as follows:
>
> 1. A variable is a lambda expression (we will use single, lower-case
>      letters for variables).
> 2. If M and N are lambda expressions, then so are each of the
>      following:
>
>    a) (M)
>       b) λid.M
>       c) MN
>
> We can express the rules given above that define the language of lambda expressions using a context-free grammar:
>   exp →   ID
>   |   ( exp )
>   |   λ ID . exp  // abstraction
>   |   exp exp // application

From rule #1 and the context-free grammar, I think the author means that `ID`  refers to `variable`, and `variable ∈ lambda expression`. But I am not sure whether `lambda expression ∈ variable`.

Question:
May I know whether I can use a "complex" expressions (e.g. a non-variable lambda expression) as `id` in `λid.M`? Intuitively, I interpret `variable` represented by an ID with a single letter, but I could not find reference to support my conjecture.
(or in other words, how is `variable` defined in lambda calculus, if this is not too broad a question?)

Comment: The phrase “A variable is a lambda expression” follows the same pattern as “a fish is an animal” or “burglary is a crime”. It does not assert that the two things are the same.

Comment: "ID" here is an abbreviation for "identifier", which is computer science jargon for "variable name". The idea here is that we have some collection of variable names (“identifiers”) already, and a λ-expression can be either a simple variable, or something in one of the three more complex forms given. For example, supposing that `a` and `b` are variables, then `λa.b` and `λa.(a a)` are λ-expressions.

Answer (score 4):

No, it cannot. Variables are lambda expressions, but not all lambda expressions are variables. You may, however, compose functions.

Comment: Looking back at this, I would add that the `id` in your example `λid.M` is a bound variable in `M`. That is, the purpose of the `λid` is to bind the name `id` so that its value is fixed in `M` (as opposed to free). If you were to apply this function to some expression `N` (e.g., `λid.M N`), then `id` would be bound to (the value of) `N`. It doesn't make sense to speak of `id` as an expression; it is just a name. But (the value of) an expression can be bound to this name.